# i am unable to use _totalSupply and _balances any private data type in OpenZeppelin and shows Undeclared identifier in solidity

Tags: solidity, erc20, openzeppelin

Hey i am unable to implement _totalSupply and _balances in Remix but able to use remaining functions like name() and decimal() and symbol()
this is my code

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
contract METoken is ERC20 {
constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20 ("MAstering ther","MET")
{
    _totalSupply=initialSupply;
    _balances[msg.sender] = initialSupply;
    emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, initialSupply);
}
}
```

i am using ERC20 and i have seen from ERC20.sol file from Github that there are _totalSupply and other variables to use the totalSupply() method but i am not able to use them plz help!

Comment: what was the error you getting ? ..  it seems like your code is working fine;

Comment: i was getting undeclared identifier on both _totalSupply and _balances but then i used _mint function for setting the totalSupply but i am still unable to use _totalSupply maybe we cannot use them directly

Answer (score 1):

In the [OpenZeppelin ERC20](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol) implementation, that you're importing to your contract, properties `_totalSupply` and `_balances` have the `private` visibility.

From the Solidity [docs page](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters):

> *Private state variables are like internal ones but they are not visible in derived contracts.*

So these specific properties (with `private` visibility) are not visible in your contract that derives from the contract that declares them.

**Solution**: The parent contract defines the `_mint()` function that effectively increases the balance of a selected address, the total supply, as well as emits the `Transfer` event.

```
constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20 ("MAstering ther","MET")
{
    // increases `msg.sender`'s balance, total supply, and emits the `Transfer` event
    _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
}
```

Comment: Hey Peter thanks for your Answer i was hoping this answer but i thought maybe there is a way to change the values directly ✌

Comment: @ParasKumar If you forked the OZ code and updated the properties visibility in your local fork, then you could change them directly. But that seems like a very long stretch and it might bring another types of issues... Why do you need to update the values directly? Maybe there's some other way (apart these that I just mentioned) more suitable to your use case.